# Dropdown w/ overflow:visible moves divs around dropdown in Safari?

Tags: css, firefox, safari, overflow

EDIT (08/09/13): You can see the error [here](http://dcturanoinc.com/blog/add/).

I have a jQuery drop-down (it replaces the standard select with a  based drop-down) that's set to overflow:visible, and in Firefox, the drop-down overflows into adjacent content like it should when clicked. But in Safari, the drop-down, even without being clicked, moves adjacent content around the drop-down. Below is a picture of what I'm talking about.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

[image]

Comment: under safafi, you need to turn off the default styling with `select { -webkit-appearance: none; }`

Comment: It's not a standard select, I'm using a jQuery plugin (msDropDown) that replaces the select w/ a `<div>`-based drop-down.

Comment: Are you 100% sure all your HTML tags are closed appropriately. The only time I see issues like this a div or something is missing its ending tag. If so post an example so we can experience it ourselves.

Comment: 100% sure, I just checked again, everything is closed properly. When overflow: visible is changed to hidden on the containing div, that gap disappears. Also just made the page public: http://dcturanoinc.com/blog/add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your gf-style.css on line 297 you have "overflow: visible". That's what is causing consistency issues. Remove that and should be fine on all browsers.

**EDIT:** That was not it, this is the solution. Add this in your CSS file:

```
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
  display: block;
}
```

And then add this class to your two_col_container div:

```
<div class="two_col_container clearfix">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Angelin. You defined display for .clearfix twice, which would it be?

Comment: that's a fix for older IE

Comment: If you choose to drop support for IE6 & 7 you should check out this great resource about clearfix: http://www.css-101.org/articles/clearfix/latest-new-clearfix-so-far.php

Comment: Thanks again Angelin, I'll award the bounty to you :)

Comment: Glad to have helped :)